# When database is bottle neck in Kafka pair?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have Kafka stream that makes intermediate calculations then puts is to mongodb.

Problem is that mongodb can not handle a lot of inserts form Kafka stream.

How do you solve this issue?

Comment: How are you writing to MongoDB? Direct from Kafka Streams?

Comment: Yes, from streams Kafka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll want to write the intermediate results out to a topic. Then use the [MongoDB Connector](https://www.mongodb.com/kafka-connector) to write to MongoDB. Kafka Connect is the preferred way to write to external systems from a Kafka topic. Here's the documentation for [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html)

Comment: There is solution allows that ksql db